# Select2 style attribute not picking up

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I am attempting to style the background color of some select2 options programmatically. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. I'm not seeing the background-color as red at all. Really what I am trying to do is set the background color for what select2 renders as an li and is the parent of the span tag in the `formatText()` function.

**EDIT:**
[image: this is currently how the list looks]

What you see here where those options are yellow, I want the whole row and not just the text to be yellow.

I also want to style individual rows in my Family drop-down to correspond with how they will be colored in my Products drop-down.

I have two sections of code that I think should be doing this. Here is the Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/8axy7123/

```
  const productsConfig = {
  width: "100%",
  theme: 'bootstrap4',
  placeholder: "Select item",
  allowClear: true,
  templateSelection: formatText,
  templateResult: formatText, 
  data: dataitems2, 
   escapeMarkup: function(m) {
      return m;
   }
};

function formatText (icon) {
if(icon.badge == undefined){
    return  $('<span>' + icon.text + '</span>');
} else {
  return  $('<span><span class="badge" style"background-color:red">'+ icon.badge.length + '</span> ' + icon.text + '</span>');
}
    
};
```

and....

```
$('#products').select2(
    Object.assign({},
    productsConfig,
    {data: null}
  )
 );


$('#fam').on('change', function() {
  // get selected value from the #fam select2
  const selected = $(this).val();
  // get the new products config (products config + data options)
  const newProductsConfig = Object.assign({},
    productsConfig,
    {data: productOptions[selected]}
  );

  // destroy the existing products select2 and re-initialize
  $('#products').empty().select2('destroy').select2(newProductsConfig);
  $('#products').val(null).trigger('change')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding another answer since I think my first answer is viable for your initial question and resolves the bug you had, and this answer does what you actually want. Your main issue is that you want to change the background color of your options, but the dropdown container is generated dynamically at the time it opens. This makes it tricky to alter the styles. However, you can somewhat hack the `theme` option in the select2 config. Normally, when you set the `theme` option it will add that string to your dropdown class prefixed by `select2-container--`. For example, if you set this config:

```
$('#example').select2({theme: 'bootstrap4'});
```

then whenever you open your dropdown, the main select2 container will have the class `select2-container--bootstrap4`. It simply appends whatever you set for `theme` to `select2-container--`, which means we can add our own class within the config like so:

```
$('#example').select2({theme: 'bootstrap4 my-custom-class'});
```

and then whenever you open your dropdown, the main select2 container will have the class `select2-container--bootstrap4` *as well as* the class `my-custom-class`.

Knowing this, you can create whatever styles you want in advance for your list items:

```
#select2-fam-results li:nth-child(1),
.select2-container.bg-red li {
  background-color: red;
}

#select2-fam-results li:nth-child(2),
.select2-container.bg-yellow li {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**EDIT NOTE:**

Notice how I also have added matching styles for your family's list element such as `#select2-fam-results li:nth-child(1)` and `#select2-fam-results li:nth-child(2)`. Since you gave an `id` of `fam` on your Family `<select>` element, the dynamically-generated `<ul>` list will always have the id corresponding id `select2-fam-results`. You have to be a bit careful here since you are hardcoding the `nth-child` index, but if you can be reasonably sure how the ordering of the Family options will appear then you can safely do this.

**END EDIT NOTE**

Now all you need to do is update your theme dynamically when `Family` is selected. Let's modify `productOptions` so that it contains both your data and the theme that you want:

```
const productOptions = {
  dataitems1: {data: dataitems1, theme: 'bg-red'},
  dataitems2: {data: dataitems2, theme: 'bg-yellow'},
};
```

Now in your `#fam` change event, all you have to do is add that theme to your existing theme:

```
$('#fam').on('change', function() {
  /* ... */
  const options = productOptions[selected];

  // get the new products config (products config + data options + theme)
  const newProductsConfig = Object.assign({}, productsConfig, {
    data: options.data,
    theme: `${productsConfig.theme} ${options.theme}`,
  });
  /* ... */
});
```

This gives you the flexibility of changing the background color for your products depending on which family you select.

*Note:* In your `productsConfig` definition you would then also have to change `data: dataitems2` to `data: dataitems2.data` or remove the line altogether since it is not actually being used.

Comment: Sorry I am just now getting back to this, last week was crazy. Boom that worked. One final question, how now do I get the family options to be yellow and red based on the specific family it is?

Comment: Updated your question and my answer based on this comment, have a look - it involves updating your CSS definitions.

Comment: Yup that worked. Thanks for the help. I set your answer as the right one and gave you an upvote

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo in that you are missing the `=` sign on your style declaration. In your `else` statement you should change the HTML from

```
<span class="badge" style"background-color:red">
```

to

```
<span class="badge" style="background-color:red">
```

I might also create a new CSS class and use that rather than using a hardcoded style. So for example you could define a CSS class like this:

```
.badge-highlight { /* name this whatever you want */
  background-color: red;
}
```

and then alter your JavaScript to contain this HTML:

```
<span class="badge badge-highlight">
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. After fixing the typos I got it working but not the way I am trying to do. If you look at the fiddle it shows the "options" with a yellow background, what select2 does is insert a <i> tag if you inspect the code in your browser. I essentially want to grab that <i> tag and give it a background color so it looks like the whole option and not just the text itself has a background color. I'm thinking using the parent() but I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Comment: I edited the OP to try to be more clear of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look